# Express.js API delete route not working

Tags: node.js, rest, express, routes, http-delete

I'm trying to make an API in express and I'm running into an error making a delete route on `/posts/:postId` Whenever I try to make a delete request to that route with postman, the page just loads infintely and the request is aborted.

Here is what my `/posts/:postId` routes look like:

```
router.route("/:postId")
.get(controllers.getSinglePost)
.delete(function(req, res){ res.send('work'); });
```

Here is what the `controllers.getSinglePost` function looks like:

`

```
exports.getSinglePost = function(req, res){
  db.Post.findById(req.params.postId)
  .populate('comments')
  .then(post=>{
    if(!post) return res.status(404).json({message: "Post not found"});
    res.status(200).json(post);
  }).catch(err=>{
    res.status(500).json(err);
  });
}
```

`

I really don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: is get working ?

Comment: Yep. It's just the delete route that's not working.

Comment: can you share what controllers.getSinglePost function looks like?

Comment: how did you refer the router? and what do you mean by the page loads infinitely? are you sure the request hit the `DELETE` part? try to put `console.log` inside the `DELETE` part

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.getSinglePost = function(req, res){
      db.Post.findById(req.params.postId)
      .populate('comments')
      .then(post=>{
        if(!post) return res.status(404).json({message: "Post not found"});
        res.status(200).json(post);
      }).catch(err=>{
        res.status(500).json(err);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your means, but you can change code to complete your work. I use sequelize ,it may be not exist the attribution of populate.here is my code ,it's successful.

```
getSinglePost = function(req, res){
  db.models.City.findById(req.params.postId)
  .then(post=>{
    if(!post) return res.status(404).json({message: "Post not found"});
    res.status(200).json(post);
  }).catch(err=>{
    res.status(500).json(err);
  });
}

app.route('/:postId')
  .get(function(req,res){
    getSinglePost(req,res)
  })
  .delete(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Update1 the book')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems like for some reason a npm package I was using called formidable was causing the issue. As soon as I removed it from the app, it started working again. Sorry to waste you guys time.